# I'm receiving images from ExpressJS as escaped string literal. How to show a real image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, express, string-literals

The title says it all. I'm able to retrieve data from ExpressJS, but I'm getting this, insead of a real image:

```
{`data: '�PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x03�\x00\x00\x02�\b\x06\x00\x00\x00|˕�\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00��\x1C�\x00\x00\x00\x06b…1 Default RGB colour space - sRGBDSH�\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND�B`�',`
```

How can I convert this to a real image? When I manually enter the URL I get a real image, but when I try to load it using my ReactJS app, I'm getting the escaped string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Express has a method for sending files:
`res.sendFile(filepath)`
this should do the job.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using, and having this issue.